# check if a .env variable is x in npm scripts

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, npm-scripts, npm-start

So I am looking to create a script in the `package.json` that runs either `start:dev` or `start:prod` if `ENV` in the `.env` file is set to dev or prod and by default - if nothing is set `start:dev` should run.

I am unsure how to check environment variables inside a npm run script.

**What I want**

Something like:

```
if ENV === dev 
  yarn start:dev 
else if ENV === prod 
  yarn start:prod 
else 
  yarn start:dev
```

*Any ideas?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the `if/elif/else` you are looking for :
(extrapolate this example to your own needs)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ "$ENV" = "DEV" ]
then
    echo "Development Mode"
elif [ "$ENV" = "PROD" ]
then
    echo "Production Mode"
else
    echo "ENV : has not been set yet..."
fi
```

Its possible to then use the .sh from the `package.json` `scripts` (example) :

```
"scripts": {"start": "./checkEnv.sh"}
```

... dont forget permissions :  `chmod +x ./checkEnv.sh`

Comment: While this is a good starting ground, I didnt know you could do this, how can I then call start:dev or start:prod? I assume I cannot call npm scripts from in the sh script? would the sh script return something? or ... ??

Comment: @TheWebs : by setting the ENV variable to DEV or PROD you will just have to do `npm start` , and it will run the .sh and it will do whatever you have under the matching conditional statement. just change the `echo`'s for the `yarn start:dev` / `yarn start:prod` . I hope you got it now :)